# How to force my custom skin to be used by all buttons in my JavaFX application?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

Suppose I wrote a new skin for Button.
In JavaFX 8 it can look like:

```
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ButtonSkin;

// This is quite dirty because of using non-stable api:
public class MyButtonSkin extends ButtonSkin {
    ...
}
```

Then I wish to use this skin in my application for every button created by `FXMLLoader` (via `<Button ...>` fxml-element)
**and** I don't want to change fxml-files.

My questions are:

*What are possibilities to do this in JavaFX 8?*

*Can be some DI-framework used to do this?*

*And what about JavaFX 9?*

---

Additional code example:

This skin introduces new `underkeypress` pseudoclass for buttons:

```
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ButtonSkin;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

public class MyButtonSkin extends ButtonSkin {
    private static final PseudoClass PSEUDO_CLASS_UNDERKEYPRESS = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("underkeypress");

    public MyButtonSkin(Button button) {
        super(button);
        button.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,
                (event -> {
                    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
                        pseudoClassStateChanged(PSEUDO_CLASS_UNDERKEYPRESS, true);
                    }
                }));
        button.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED,
                (event -> {
                    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
                        pseudoClassStateChanged(PSEUDO_CLASS_UNDERKEYPRESS, false);
                    }
                }));
    }
}
```

That pseudoclass should be used via CSS like:

```
.button:underkeypress {
    -fx-base: red;
}
```

Comment: skin is a styleable property, so you can register your custom skin as default via css, something like `.button { -fx-skin: "mypackage.MyButtonSkin" };`

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks! You're first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @kleopatra noted the best way to apply the skin to all `Button`s in your scene is using a CSS stylesheet.

```css
.button {
    -fx-skin: "my.package.MyButtonSkin";
}
```

apply this stylesheet to the root of the scene

```
Parent root = loader.load(); // load fxml
root.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
```

---

AFAIK there is no easier way in JavaFX 9 for this. The only difference is that `ButtonSkin` was moved to the public API, see [`javafx.scene.control.skin.ButtonSkin`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/skin/ButtonSkin.html).

Comment: Thanks! I only wish to mention the stylesheet can be loaded for whole application with `Application.setUserAgentStylesheet(Application.STYLESHEET_MODENA); StyleManager.getInstance().addUserAgentStylesheet(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());` before of creation of any `FXMLLoader` instances.